# Most useful low HD animals for Embrace the Wild?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

In our campaign we are using the Complete Adventurer version of Embrace the Wild that grants the caster the extraordinary senses of a chosen animal. As a druid, I salivate at the thought of getting blindsight and casting obscuring mist, or similar tactics. However, I am having trouble finding low HD animals that have very useful abilities (I am currently level 3). There are plenty of animals with lesser senses like blindsense or low-light vision, but few with blindsight or darkvision.

Can anyone suggest a set of representative animals that I could use as a reference for getting the best use out of this spell?

Answer (score 1):

[Porpoise](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/porpoise.htm)

2HD. Blindsight 120'. You really can't do much better.

Comment: Yeah, I did run across the porpoise when I was looking through the SRD for animals.  I'm concerned, though, that my DM will not allow this ability to function outside of water.  By RAW it seems fine, but if we take the flavor even a little seriously, it seems like a stretch.

Comment: @shaydwyrm You could always use that same logic to argue that a bat *really* has blindsight, and not blindsense.  They can track the position/velocity/location of small insects, and notice obstacles with the resolution of a single hair.  So if you go by the RAW, porpoises; if what makes sense, argue for [bats](http://www.nhm.ac.uk/nature-online/life/mammals/bats/session3/).  :)

Comment: Is there any reason why a porpoise would not be able to echo-locate above the water? A bat can do it.